# What is the purpose of this delegate in the main method?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm learning about delegates. This is example code (first) from a LinkedIn tutorial on C#. I am unable to identify the advantage and purpose of using the delegate. Its unclear what the reasons are we would not call the function directly. I retyped my own code (second) that appears to give a similar result.

```
namespace Delegates1._10._2018

{
    public delegate string MyDelegate(int arg1, int arg2);

    internal class Program
    {  
        static string func1(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b).ToString();
        }

        static string func2(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a * b).ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDelegate f = func1;
            Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + f(10,20));
            f = func2;
            Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + f(10,20));
        }
    }
}



internal class Program
    {
        public static int func1(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }
        public static int func2(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a * b);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + func1(10, 20));
            Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + func2(10, 20));
        }
    }
```

The number is: 30
The number is: 200

Answer (score 2):

The delegate is just declaring the shape of a method (`public delegate string MyDelegate(int arg1, int arg2);`. You can change which method is called as shown in your first `Main` method. This is a contrived example, which doesn't have much benefit as it doesn't deal with external data or input to manipulate the behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by 'shape of a method'? And in both case (the first original and second my own), I thought I changed which method was called. But without using the delegate. So I don't understand the real purpose.

Comment: @jkuehlin look up the strategy pattern.

Comment: A better way to say "shape of the method" is to say "method signature".  The signature of the `MyDelegate` `delegate` is _a method that takes two integers and returns a string_.  A variable that is typed as a `MyDelegate` can refer to any function that has that method signature, so `func1` and `func2` fit the bill

Answer (score 0):

The example is bad!. Let me try to explain:

We have a Class Car, the Car does not know how to drive itself, the Person sitting in the Car, knows how to drive it. So the Car Asks to the Person (Delegate) Drive me!

```
public delegate int DriveMeWithSpeed(int maxForceOnPedal);
    public class Car
    {
        DriveMeWithSpeed speedy;

        public Car(DriveMeWithSpeed YourSpeed)
        {
            speedy = YourSpeed;
        }

        public void Drive()
        {
            if (speedy != null) speedy(100);
        }

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int IDrive(int PedalForce)
        {
            return 40;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person Me = new Person();

            Car myCar = new Car(Me.IDrive);
            myCar.Drive();
        }
```

So main concept is that the class itself does not always know the functionality of a function so it delegates this to the class who knows what to do.